# Difference between division in SELECT vs in the UPDATE, SET statements in SQL

Tags: sql, select, set

I have two values that need to be divided, the SELECT statement gives me all the decimal places whereas the SET statement will only give me two.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST(
                UNIT_1 [DECIMAL](18,2) NULL,
                UNIT_2 [DECIMAL](18,2) NULL,
                DIVISION [DECIMAL](18,2) NULL
                )
INSERT INTO #TEST (UNIT_1, UNIT_2) VALUES (1185.00, 101614.00)
--1) 
SELECT UNIT_1 / UNIT_2 AS DIVISION FROM #TEST
--2)
UPDATE #TEST 
SET DIVISION = UNIT_1 / UNIT_2
SELECT * FROM #TEST
```

The results I want are in 1 yet I need to use the UPDATE, SET statement as I will be using WHERE as well.

```
1 - 0.01166177888873580412
2 - 0.01
```

I've tried cast, convert, round, but can't seem to break this one

Comment: in the first case it gets autonatocally converted, and the second truncs it

Comment: You defined the field as precision two: `DIVISION [DECIMAL](18,2) NULL`  So when the result is stored in that field, it's only two digits after the decimal because you defined the field that way.  When you SELECT, it's not referencing the data type of the DIVISION column -- it's simply returning the result of the SELECT to you (even if you alias the result as DIVISION, it isn't related to the column with that name)

Comment: Change the data type on the DIVISION column from precision 2 to precision 12 (or however many digits you want after the decimal).  You may also need to adjust the scale, depending on how large you expect the numbers to be.

Comment: Also, side note:  it's generally considered unnecessary to store calculations that can easily be done in queries.  Why store the result of division of two numbers when you can just get the result in a query?

Comment: @devlincarnate Thats exactly it, the precision needs to be changed to allot more decimal places. This is just an example of a step that I needed changed. In my actual query this update statement I would only need this calculation on specific rows hence my use for WHERE. Thank you for the insights!

Answer (score 1):

@devlin carnate got the solution.

The precision needs changing for 'DIVISION', if this is increased to n decimal places the results will work. Thank you!